# How to increase the size of the displayed text in a Gtk::ComboBoxText in Gtkmm?

Tags: c++, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I have included a combo text box in my GUI however, the size of the text visible inside the box is too small compared to the size of the ComboTextBox. Is there a way I can increase this display size? I am using **gtkmm-3.0** along with **Glade** to set my elements.
[image]

Update: I tried the following in my code, however it is **not working**!

```
Gtk::ComboBoxText* ComboBox;
refbuilder->get_widget("ComboBoxText_glade", ComboBox);
ComboBox->append("01", "A");
ComboBox->append("02", "B");

auto context = ComboBox->get_pango_context();
auto fontDescrip = context->get_font_description();
fontDescrip.set_family("Ubuntu Thin");
fontDescrip.set_absolute_size(10*Pango::SCALE);
context->set_font_description(fontDescrip);
```

Comment: FYI: [Changing font style in PyGTK ComboBox](http://handyfloss.net/2009.06/changing-font-style-in-pygtk-combobox/)

Comment: Is it possible in C++? @Scheff'sCat

Comment: If this is possible in PyGTK, why it shouldn't be possible in C++? PyGTK is actually yet another API binding for GTK.

Comment: Is it possible for you to show it in an example? @Scheff'sCat?

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Please check if the method I applied was correct.